# ambiguous error in transpose row to column in mysql

Tags: mysql

tbl_attendance

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_instructor_info` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `InstructorID` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Mobile` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Trade` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `TSP` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `InstructorID` (`InstructorID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

tbl_assigned

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_assigned` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Round` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TraineeID` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mobile` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BatchID` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Remarks` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `District` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comments` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Level` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Trade` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Photo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `TraineeID` (`TraineeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=356 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

tbl_instructor_info

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_attendance` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TraineeID` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `attnDate` date NOT NULL,
  `inTime` time NOT NULL,
  `outTime` time NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=316 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Getting ambiguous error in `TraineeID`. I used `varchar` type data for `TraineeID`. Where clause also generating error. pleas help me to get this result.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= ', `TraineeID`, ',"P","A")) AS ID',`TraineeID`)
            ) INTO @sql
    FROM tbl_attendance t1 JOIN tbl_assigned t2 
    ON t1.TraineeID=t2.TraineeID
    WHERE t2.BatchID='ID-Electronics/FMMTTC-01M/R7/01';  
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(attnDate,"%d-%m-%Y")AS Date, ', @sql, ' 
    FROM tbl_attendance
    WHERE attnDate BETWEEN ',2015-12-01,' and ',2015-12-02,'
    GROUP BY attnDate');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

some of `TraineeID`s in `tbl_attendance` which are not in `tbl_assigned` table. Actually `TraineeID`s in `tbl_attendance` would match with two data table. one is `tbl_assigned` table and other one is `tbl_Instructor_Info`. Should I use like below:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX(IF(`t1.TraineeID`= ', `t1.TraineeID` or `t3.InstructorID`, ',"P","A")) AS ID',`t1.TraineeID`)
            ) INTO @sql
    FROM tbl_attendance t1 
    JOIN tbl_assigned t2 ON t1.TraineeID=t2.TraineeID
    Join tbl_instructor_info t3 ON t1.TraineeID=t3.InstructorID
    WHERE t2.BatchID='ID-Electronics/FMMTTC-01M/R7/01';  
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(attnDate,"%d-%m-%Y")AS Date, ', @sql, ' 
    FROM tbl_attendance
    WHERE attnDate BETWEEN ',2015-12-01,' and ',2015-12-02,'
    GROUP BY attnDate');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

here is the dump without any criteria;
query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= ', `TraineeID`, ',"P","A")) AS ID',`TraineeID`)
            ) INTO @sql
    FROM tbl_attendance;  

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(attnDate,"%d-%m-%Y")AS Date, ', @sql, ' 
    FROM tbl_attendance
    WHERE attnDate BETWEEN ',2015-12-01,' and ',2015-12-02,'
    GROUP BY attnDate');

select @sql as aboutToUse;

-- PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
-- EXECUTE stmt;
-- DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**dump data:**
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(attnDate,"%d-%m-%Y")AS Date, MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 22779,"P","A")) AS ID22779,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 22780,"P","A")) AS ID22780,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 24321,"P","A")) AS ID24321,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 24870,"P","A")) AS ID24870,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 24871,"P","A")) AS ID24871,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25099,"P","A")) AS ID25099,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25199,"P","A")) AS ID25199,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25304,"P","A")) AS ID25304,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25308,"P","A")) AS ID25308,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25515,"P","A")) AS ID25515,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25549,"P","A")) AS ID25549,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25552,"P","A")) AS ID25552,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25560,"P","A")) AS ID25560,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25571,"P","A")) AS ID25571,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25592,"P","A")) AS ID25592,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25594,"P","A")) AS ID25594,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25597,"P","A")) AS ID25597,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25600,"P","A")) AS ID25600,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 25710,"P","A")) AS ID25710,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 26105,"P","A")) AS ID26105,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 26145,"P","A")) AS ID26145,MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= 26147,"P","A")) A 
        FROM tbl_attendance
        WHERE attnDate BETWEEN 2002 and 2001
        GROUP BY attnDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on this line

```
CONCAT('MAX(IF(`TraineeID`= ', `TraineeID`, ',"P","A")) AS ID',`TraineeID`)
```

you need to specify which table alias (`t1` or `t2`) for `TraineeID`

as that column appears in both.

until then,

> 1052: Column 'TraineeID' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: CONCAT('MAX(IF(`t1.TraineeID`= ', `t1.TraineeID`, ',"P","A")) AS ID',`t1.TraineeID`) trying with this but it show unknown column t1.TraineeID

Comment: I would always do something like this: http://pastie.org/10610404  ... way before I would attempt to run it. What does that give you

Comment: your top 2 tables have that column name like I said. I also showed a pastie 2 comments up to show how to dump out the string you are about to execute. Show that. So if you would like me to help, I need to see the schema (not a picture but text), and that string 2 comments up. Good luck

Comment: ok, it looks like you changed the question to another query to avoid the 1052 ambiguous column error. Thanks for showing the tables in text format! So this question is answered as I see it

Comment: sir, still not solve yet. I just show you the last bottom query that you get that what I want actually@Drew

Comment: ok so you are still getting a 1052? And if so, are you going to publish what that string is that I showed in the pastie how to display it? Because you haven't done that yet. When you do, I have your three tables in your db (in *my* db) and I can get a better grasp on it. Thanks

Comment: sir, I just edit with dump data without any criteria. And it warned `row 22 cut by GROUP CONCAT()`.  If I use to criteria within this query it does not run. pleas take look.

Comment: I ran that it works. Now can you show me one that does not work

Comment: so we simply have solved the ambiguous column that this question was about. So this question is answered. On the stack we don't then expand it into why are my columns too short, or on to the next error or warning. So please mark this as Answered with the Green Check mark

Comment: That said, you can always join me in my chat room and I can help solve this for you: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/random-musings-drew